# Laravel 4 query paginate associated model

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-4

I'm trying to paginate this query by sellorders.

```
$user = User::with('sellorders', 'sellorders.sellorderitems', 'sellorders.sellorderitems.status', 'sellorders.sellorderitems.device', 'sellorders.sellorderitems.device.brand')->find(\Sentry::getUser()->id);
```

What arguments can I pass to the paginate method to paginate the sellorder instead of the user? Can't seem to find what I'm looking for in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are trying to paginate a particular user's sellorders.

My advice would be to adjust your code to something like:

```
$user = \Sentry::getUser();
if ($user) {
    $sellorders = $user->sellorders()->paginate(15);
}
```

This assumes you have the sellorders relationship set up correctly on your User model (and that you have extended Sentry's User model to do so, and configured Sentry to use your model: see https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/issues/161).